# How do I write a subquery using a JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have the following code to retrieve and display the first and last names of writers who are also editors (ED_ID = WRT_ID).

```
SELECT Writers.WRT_LastName AS LastName, Writers.WRT_FirstName AS FirstName
FROM Writers INNER JOIN Editors ON Editors.ED_ID = Writers.WRT_ID;
```

It produces the results I want, but how would I write it using a subquery and produce the same results?

I am using Access 2013

Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you don't want duplicate results.  I point that out, because the subquery is going to be different from the `join` if the `Editors` table has duplicates.

Typical ways of writing this are using `IN` or `EXISTS`.  I tend to go with the latter, although the two are usually pretty equivalent performance wise (on the other hand, `NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `NOT IN` semantically).

```
SELECT Writers.WRT_LastName AS LastName, Writers.WRT_FirstName AS FirstName
FROM Writers 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Editors WHERE Editors.ED_ID = Writers.WRT_ID);
```

Comment: So if one if the tables were to have duplicates, I should use EXISTS rather than IN?

Comment: and what does SELECT 1 do in the subquery?

Comment: @Ddrossi93 . . . `EXISTS` just checks for the existence of a row.  The `1` is arbitrary.  `EXISTS` and `IN` do the same thing.  The `JOIN` can produce duplicates if `Editors` has duplicate writers in it.  The conditions in the `WHERE` clause will not duplicate the results, so the result sets are not always identical.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the join conditions into a where clause subquery:

```
SELECT WRT_LastName as LastName, WRT_FirstName as FirstName
FROM   WRITERS
WHERE  WRT_ID in (SELECT ED_ID FROM EDITORS)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Is that how it always works when replacing JOINs with subqueries?

Comment: Yes exactly.  You just have to match up the logic.  In the join query, you are using the join to filter out WRT_IDs from the WRITERS table that don't have a matching ED_ID in the EDITORS table.  Transfer that same logic to the where clause and you have the subquery version.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a pretty good read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query it touches on what Gordon mentioned above (subqueries will naturally filter out duplicates, joins will not), and has some interesting info about performance pros and cons.